# How do I print labels with a Brother PT-9500PC?

Tags: printing, brother

We are converting our company from Windows to Ubuntu and we need to print technical labels with Brother PT-9500PC printer connected over USB directly to the computer. Ubuntu does have the driver in ptouch-driver package and I can even install it but nothing more. Every time I try to print something from GIMP/Inkscape/GLables3 only blank label prints with nothing on it. I use 36mm label with 36x30mm option manually selected in GIMP/Inkscape/GLables3.

I can't log into `http://localhost:631/` to change something because it does not accept my username and password (I tried almost every guide but it seems broken).

Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit,
ASUS 1015BX,
AMD C-60,
4GB RAM,
120GB OCZ SSD

and

Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit,
HP TX2,
AMD Turion X2 ZM-84,
4GB RAM,
2x 500GB HDD

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Brother Drivers for Linux® distributions](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/index.html) website. You will find there official solutions.

Here you will find instructions regarding pre-requierd procedure for installing [P-touch/QL-Printer drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/before.html#203). This [link](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_esp.html#PT-9500) will get you to webpage with the drivers for PT-9500. Notice the links to installation instructions at the bottom of that table.

Brother states that installation to 64bit distributions is not supported for P-touch/QL-Printer, but maybe they are wrong. I have Brother DCP-135C and it can be installed on 64bit system (drivers are only for i386). They have [FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html#f00081) for using Brother Linux printer drivers on 64bit Linux and also similar for [scanners](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101).

There is also [Brother Drivers Installer for Linux Users](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html#f00104) shell script.

Comment: The ptouch-driver package should have this driver already inside. If not then this is serious bug.
The driver is for i386 I have 64bit OS and I need to use it (because of 4GB RAM).
I already have the psutils package.
I can use Google too and I already did so... For like 3 hours...

Comment: All these links are dead.